# How to add timeout to knex transactions and schema raw?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I am getting an error when running a long query: `canceling statement due to statement timeout`

So, I am trying to increase the timeout for this query. I have read the [documentation](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-timeout) on Knex but they only specify how to increase the timeout when using the Query Builder. I am using `raw` which allows me to pass in a query and not use the Query Builder. Is there a way to pass a timeout variable when using `transaction` and `raw`? Is it possible to increase the timeout in the Knex object on initialization?

This is what my code looks like:

```
knex.transaction(function(trx){
    trx.schema.raw(query)
        .then(function(res){
            // do stuff with res
            // trx.commit
        }).catch(function(err){
            // catch err
            // trx.commit or rollback
        });
```

I have tried putting the timeout after knex such as `knex.timeout(600000)` as specified in the documents but I just get `knex.timeout is not a function`

Any help would be great

Comment: See the following: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/518

Comment: Yes, I am aware that you can change it in postgres, but I was hoping there was a way to do it on a per-query basis. I don't want every query to have default+10 minutes to run, just the ones that take long.

Comment: that's your only option, I'm afraid. Although you can do it artificially, via client-side timeout, but the query will continue execution in the meantime, which isn't good.

Comment: Do you know if using the `timeout()` function changes that variable or is it a different variable? For example, if the postgres variable was set to 1 minute, but I set the timeout to 10 minutes with `timeout()`, would the lower timeout (1 minute) be enforced or overwritten (10 minutes)?